# Git-tf commands throwing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I noticed after recently upgrading to mountain lion all git tf commands such as `git tf checkin` throw the following expection:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.nativeEnableEcho()Z
at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.nativeEnableEcho(Native Method)
at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.enableEcho(NativeConsole.java:56)
at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.ConsoleUtils.enableEcho(ConsoleUtils.java:47)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.prompt(Command.java:464)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.promptForPassword(Command.java:436)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.promptForCredentials(Command.java:424)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getDefaultCredentials(Command.java:288)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getCredentials(Command.java:306)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:324)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlClient(Command.java:474)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.CheckinCommand.run(CheckinCommand.java:193)
at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:328)
```

I've tried updating git, git-tf and java runtime but I'm still seeing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: Feb 4, 2013

### The developers for this project have added an update the fixes this issue and adds support for java 7 for newer versions of osx 10.7+, The updates can be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474

This is a known issue for osx 10.8.2 related to the latest version of java 1.7.0 that comes with this release. The suggested work around by the git-tf project team is to use a later version of java 1.6.0 while executing commands for git-tf.